# Extract string between first occurring set of parenthesis

Tags: performance, php, strings

I have this function and need to refactor it

Please refactor the code below to make it more concise, efficient and readable with good logic flow

```
function findFirstStringInBracket($str){
    if(strlen($str) > 0){
        $firstbracket = strstr($str, '(');
        if($firstbracket){
            $firstbracket = ltrim($firstbracket, '(');
            return strstr($firstbracket, ')', true);
        }else{
            return '';
        }
    }else{
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a homework

Comment: The current title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please explain the code you posted. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find my snippet below to be direct, concise, and readable (but I rarely have any trouble reading regex patterns).

The pattern literally matches the first occurring opening parenthesis, then captures one or more non-closing-parenthesis characters, then matches the required closing parenthesis.

A regex approach means a single function call solution and only one `return` in your custom function (which makes your code cleaner to read).

Other devs may prefer to avoid regex, but I think this is a perfect case for employing it.

**One note of difference between my script and yours, is that if the closing parenthesis is missing in the input string with your script, your function will return `false`.  My script will always return a string.**  (see [here](https://3v4l.org/CDeE0))

Code:

```
function findFirstStringInBracket(string $string): string
{
    return preg_match('~\(([^)]+)\)~', $string, $match) ? $match[1] : '';
}
```

Unless you are doing hundreds of thousands of iterations of this call, performance probably isn't an issue.  If it is a bottle neck, then you probably want to look at other ways to improve script performance.

[(Demo with some test cases)](https://3v4l.org/dRYEI)

```
$strings = [
    'the(crow)bar',
    'foo()bar',
    'handlebar()',
    '()foofighters',
    '(foobar)',
    '()',
    'barfood',
    'barf(oo',
    'fooeybar)',
    ')foob(',
];

$result = [];
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $result[$string] = preg_match('~\(([^)]+)\)~', $string, $match) ? $match[1] : '';
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'the(crow)bar' => 'crow',
  'foo()bar' => '',
  'handlebar()' => '',
  '()foofighters' => '',
  '(foobar)' => 'foobar',
  '()' => '',
  'barfood' => '',
  'barf(oo' => '',
  'fooeybar)' => '',
  ')foob(' => '',
)
```